# Cannot open Super Crate Box

Tags: macos, games

After downloading Super Crate Box from the website www.supercratebox.com, the following dialog box appears when I try to open it.[image]

Using OS X 10.9.3 on a 2013 MacBook Air. I have tried using different browsers to download the file and saving it in different locations.

Comment: try the version from iTune store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to fix this after searching and searching other programs that had this error. I used the command `xattr` to remove the extended attributes on the file.

```
sudo xattr -rc Super\ Crate\ Box.app/
```

The program then opens and runs as it should!

Comment: Doesn't work. Although it allows the app to launch, it breaks the save feature.

Answer (score 1):

That file is corrupt and is damaged on the server. Send their tech support an email with this info and ask if they have noticed the issue.

Comment: The download from the site today is corrupt - everyone that downloads it now gets the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Try uncompressing the file with a different app. When I used the otherwise great [Keka](http://www.kekaosx.com/en/), I would get these same kind of errors after uncompressing apps. I recommend [The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver) as I have not heard of this problem happening with it.